# Проблема с записью в массив

Tags: javascript, массивы

```
for(var i in clans){
        for(var a in clans[i].users){
            if(clans[i].users[a].rank!="участник"){
                loger.log(clans[i].users[a].id)
                leads.push(clans[i].users[a].id)
            }
        }
    }
```

В логере все отображается, а в массив не записывается.

Comment: А где сам массив? Объявлен ли он?

Comment: Да объявлен за for

Comment: При простом выводе clans[i].users[a].id, оно что-то выдаёт?

Comment: да выдает айди.

Comment: Попробуйте в leads через push добавить какое-то статическое значение.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов `var leads=[]
for(var i in clans){
  for(var a in clans[i].users){
   if(clans[i].users[a].rank!="участник"){
    leads.push("hm")
    loger.log(leads)
    loger.log(clans[i].users[a].id)
    leads.push(clans[i].users[a].id)
   }
  }
 }
 loger.log(leads)`

Comment: в форе массив показывает, а после нет. Хоть и leads объявлен за for

Comment: А рабочий пример можно предоставить? По этому куску ничего не понятно что откуда берется, где что объявлено и так далее ... Если брать этот кусок, то проблем никаких у вас нет, вердикт - "возможно баг".

Comment: Покажите весь код.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов `var ids=[]
 var fids=[]
 var leads=[];
 for(var i in users){
  ids.push(users[i].id)
  fids.push(users[i].fake_id)
 }
 for(var i in clans){
  for(var a in clans[i].users){
   if(clans[i].users[a].rank!="участник"){
    leads.push("hm")
    loger.log(leads)
    loger.log(clans[i].users[a].id)
    leads.push(clans[i].users[a].id)
   }
  }
 }
 loger.log(leads)`

Comment: Попробуйте обратится так window.leads.push...

Answer (score 1):

**Не является ответом**, просто воспроизвел примерный объект с которым этот код работает, может кому так будет проще разбираться (правда вроде все и так работает):

```js
var clans = [
  {
    users: [
      { id: 1, rank: 'участник' },
      { id: 2, rank: 'не участник' }
    ]
  },
  {
    users: [
      { id: 3, rank: 'участник' },
      { id: 4, rank: 'не участник' }
    ]
  }
];
var users = [
  { id: 1, fake_id: 'fake 1' },
  { id: 2, fake_id: 'fake 2' },
  { id: 3, fake_id: 'fake 3' },
  { id: 4, fake_id: 'fake 4' }
];
var ids = [];
var fids = [];
var leads = [];

for (var i in users) {
  ids.push(users[i].id);
  fids.push(users[i].fake_id);
}

for (var i in clans) {
  for (var a in clans[i].users) {
    if (clans[i].users[a].rank != "участник") {
      console.log(clans[i].users[a].id);
      leads.push(clans[i].users[a].id);
    }
  }
}

console.log(leads);
```